# Ignore Where Clause if condition variable is null

Tags: html, mysql, django

I am using output of html into my django code, if it is null I want mysql query to ignore where clause and if it has value, use in query.

below is my html:

```
 <form method="post" novalidate>
      {% csrf_token %}
     <input type="text" name="param1" placeholder="param1">
     <input type="text" name="param2" placeholder="param">
     <input type="text" name="param3" placeholder="param3">
     <input type="submit" name="fetchdata" value="Fetch Data">
     <br>
    </form>
```

How it is possible in MySQL :

```
def current_cfg(request):
    if request.POST.get("fetchdata"):
        param1=request.POST["param1"]
        param2=request.POST["param2"]   <----aaaa from html as input
        param3=request.POST["param3"]
    else:
        RNC='RRRNCH02'
        MO='CORRMALGOSWITCH'
        parameterid='DRASWITCH_DRA_VOICE_SAVE_CE_SWITCH'

    conn=db.connect(host='localhost', user='update_db', passwd='1qaz!QAZ', db='rnc_parameters')c=conn.cursor()
    c=conn.cursor()
    c.execute("""select * from rnc_parameters.current_para where (if param1 is null ignore it else param1='aaaaa')""")
    current_stats=c.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    current_stats=list(current_stats)
    return render(request,'current.html',{'current_stats':current_stats, 'MO':MO})
```

can you help me with to correctly define below part :

```
    c.execute("""select * from rnc_parameters.current_para where (if param1 is null ignore it else param1='aaaaa')""")
```

Comment: What do you mean with *ignore*? *Included* it in the result, or *exclude* it in the result? Is there by the way a reason why you did not use the ORM?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I mean exlude from query

Comment: But you thus mean if the *value* (so here `'aaa'` is `None`)?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem suppose that it can be None of 'aaaa'. I want a write down a query that if param1 is None, exclude from where clause and if it is 'aaaa' include in query

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I am not using ORM bcz I am using external db, my django db is sqlite3 and I am fetching data from mysql db

Comment: but you can manage multiple databases with Django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## *In* the MySQL query

Based on the comments, I have the idea that the variable `param2` itself can be `None`, in which case you do not want to filter on this.

We can do this with a query like:

```
SELECT *
FROM rnc_parameters.current_para
WHERE (%s IS NULL OR param1='%s')
```

we thus repeat the value twice, and in case the parameter is `NULL` the first part of the condition is always `TRUE` hence no filtering is applied. In case the parameter is *not* `NULL`, the first part is `FALSE` and thus the condition depends on the value of `param1`.

We can chain these together like:

```
SELECT *
FROM rnc_parameters.current_para
WHERE (%s IS NULL OR param1='%s')
  AND (%s IS NULL OR param2='%s')
  AND (%s IS NULL OR param3='%s')
```

with as parameters `[param1, param1, param2, param2, param3, param3]`.

## Handling when *building* the query

An alternative is constructing the query dynamically. For example:

```
cond = []
vars = []
if param1 is not None:
    cond.append("param1 = '%s'")
    vars.append(param1)
if param2 is not None:
    cond.append("param2 = '%s'")
    vars.append(param1)
if param3 is not None:
    cond.append("param3 = '%s'")
    vars.append(param1)
query = """SELECT * FROM rnc_parameters.current_para"""
if cond:
    query += " WHERE " + " AND ".join(cond)
```

and then call the query with `vars` as parameters.

Nevertheless, both approaches are inelegant, and I would advice using the ORM instead.

Answer (score 0):

i think you mean this:

```
WHERE (param1 is null OR param1='aaaaa')
```

Comment: `param is null`  is not equal to `ignore` it,they have difference

Comment: Well here in case `param1` is `NULL`, then the check holds, so regardless whether `param1` is `'aaa'` or not, it will be incuded (hence not removed), otherwise we will need to check if `param1` is `'aaaa'`. In case ignoring means removing, the `OR` needs to be replaced with an `AND` (which is basically what you did in your answer).