# Optional where condition with List input variable

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I'm trying to ignore condition when the input is null. There are already a lot of [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51361278/18514407) on stackoverflow dealing with this situation but I've not been able to find one with a `List` input variable.
The mentionned solution does not work as `IN null` raises an error. That's why I added a `COALESCE` :

*:toto* type : `List<Integer>`

```
SELECT *
FROM test_table
WHERE (:toto is null OR year IN (COALESCE(:toto, (1, 2))))
```

Problem is that `COALESCE` itself returns an error :
`COALESCE types bytea and record cannot be matched`
Strangest thing is that this query is working with a null input if I'm making a raw query directly onto the database.  I'm suspecting JPA to don't give a real null value to `:toto`.
Any solution leading to make index working and providing the correct behavior would be ok.

Comment: can you first try `SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE (:toto is null);  ` or  `select count(*) FROM test_table WHERE (:toto is null);  ` in jpa. I suspect the issue is that you parameter passed is  the column identifier rather than values.  Obviously raw query `select * FROM test_table WHERE columna is null  ` will ok in jpa.

Comment: I've performed your first request, and indeed, when :toto is null, it retrieves all the rows but when it is not null I got the following error : `argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type record`